# Average time spent on coding problems

Tags: performance

What is a good time limit to aim for when working on problems from Top Coder, UVA, SPOJ, CodeJam, etc.

I assume your coding experience correlates with your time spent so please also state the amount of coding experience for each time limit you provide.

Answer (score 2):

The time-spent is going to vary based on your abilities, knowledge, experience, and time-requirements. There's really no simpler answer in all honesty. All I could suggest is to order the issues you handle by importance, so you don't spend the most time up front on the least important items.

Answer (score 2):

I would focus on trying to solve the problems first.  *Then* you can worry about getting faster.